# "unrecognised service" for my new systemd script

Tags: ubuntu, systemd

I created a new systemd script `/etc/systemd/system/foo.service`

```
[Unit]
Description="My foo script"
Before=network-pre.target
Wants=network-pre.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/foo
```

When I run `service start foo` or `service start foo.service`

```
start: unrecognized service
```

What's wrong? Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `service` command puts the *object* first:

```
service foo start
```

The *`systemctl`* command does the opposite:

```
systemctl start foo
```

Comment: Thanks. Mind telling me what I need to do to make it start before networking comes up at boot? (It works correctly as `service foo start`) I thought the `Before=network-pre.target` would be enough but apparently not.